# Adding a line break after title in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, pygooglechart

I am trying to put a line break after a title in Google Charts or before the chart starts (I have a column chart with defined axis, but not single data cell or tab). Is there any possibility to do so in Google Charts?

I can't seem to find a good answer.

The fronts are written in html/css and jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Append  break in your title.

Before `"I am Title"`

Now  `"I am Title\r\n/I am chart"`

It will display like this

```
 I am Title 
 I am Chart
```

At I am Chart you can add your chart
Its better to add line break from backend from where you are getting the data.

I use C# so I would have done at backend like this

```
Title + Environment.NewLine + Chart
```

Comment: the \r\n method doesn't work. I need blank spaces in between the title and the chart.

I will perhaps create another topic in which I will ask on how to make a backend method for the title change in Python.

Thanks :)